# Can apache FileUtils.writeLines() be made to append to a file if it exists

Tags: java, append, apache-commons, java-io

The commons [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) look pretty cool, and I can't believe that they cannot be made to append to a file.

```
File file = new File(path);
FileUtils.writeLines(file, printStats(new DateTime(), headerRequired));
```

The above just replaces the contents of the file each time, and I would just like to keep tagging this stuff to end just as this code does.

```
fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
try{
    for(String line : printStats(new DateTime(), headerRequired)){
        fw.write(line + "\n");
    }
}
finally{ 
    fw.close();
}
```

I've searched the javadoc but found nothing!  What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [IOUtils.writeLines()](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#writeLines(java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.Writer)), it receives a Writer object which you can initialize like in your second example.

Comment: so i should put true in lines "the lines to write, null entries produce blank lines"?

Answer (score 5):

Their is now method like appendString(...) in the FileUtils class.

But you can get the Outputstream from *FileUtils.openOutputStream(...)* and than write to it by using

```
write(byte[] b, int off, int len)
```

You can calculte the off, so that you will apend to the file.

**EDIT**

After reading Davids answer i recognized that the BufferedWriter will do this job for you

```
BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(simFile));
output.append(text);
```

Comment: I would also include a output.flush() to write the stream to the file.

Answer (score 2):

As of apache FileUtils 2.1 you have this method:

static void write(File file, CharSequence data, boolean append)

Answer (score 1):

There is an overload for FileUtils.writelines() which takes parameter on whether to append.

```
public static void writeLines(File file,
          Collection<?> lines,
          boolean append)
                   throws IOException
```

file - the file to write to

lines - the lines to write, null entries produce blank lines

append - if true, then the lines will be added to the end of the file rather than overwriting

Case1:

```
FileUtils.writeLine(file_to_write, "line 1");
FileUtils.writeLine(file_to_write, "line 2");
```

file_to_write will contain only

```
line 2
```

As first writing to the same file multiple times will overwrite the file.

Case2:

```
FileUtils.writeLine(file_to_write, "line 1");
FileUtils.writeLine(file_to_write, "line 2", true);
```

file_to_write will contain

```
line 1
line 2
```

The second call will append to the same file.

Check this from java official documentation for more details.
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeLines(java.io.File, java.util.Collection, boolean)

Comment: Simply posting an external link for an answer isn't appropriate for SO. Try explaining it.

Comment: Thanks @sparky. Left it that way as java official documentation was simple and self explanatory. However edited my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like

```
List x = FileUtils.readLines(file);
x.add(String)
FileUtils.writelines(file,x);
```